# How to slim down Ubuntu GNOME title bar fatness?

Tags: gnome, configuration, customization, window, titlebar

Previously the title bars for windows were much thinner than they are now on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 with GNOME 3.20. Why is this and how can I change this? I liked the slim look I got with the `numix-gtk-theme`, but for some reason I don't get that slim look any more. Not with any theme.

This is how fat it is:

[image: Title bar fatness]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're seeing this fatter title bar because you're using Gnome-Shell. In Gnome-Shell, the title bars of Numix theme are much fatter than the versions for Unity.

Check these two images

1. Unity

   [image: numix in unity]
2. Gnome Shell

   [image: numix in gnome-shell]

#### To reduce the titlebar's fatness

To reduce this fatness, follow these steps

1. Create a file in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` with these contents

```css
.header-bar.default-decoration {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    }

.header-bar.default-decoration .button.titlebutton {
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
}

/* No line below the title bar */
.ssd .titlebar {
    border-width: 2px;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

2. Log out and Login again.

   A screenshot from gnome-shell session after change

   [image: zenity dialog after changing]

However, It's reported that this tweak doesn't work for GNOME 3.20 sometimes. To tackle that, you may need the solution from this question

- [How to change the titlebar height in standard GTK apps and those with headerbars/CSDs on Gnome 3.20](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276951/how-to-change-the-titlebar-height-in-standard-gtk-apps-and-those-with-headerbars?noredirect=1&lq=1)

<sup>Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257163/reduce-title-bar-height-in-gnome-3-gtk-3</sup>

Comment: Ah, and is there no way to change this?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda modifying source is the way I believe

Comment: So there is no GNOME Shell Extension to do this or anything?

Comment: Didn't worked for me. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/291040/249545 did the trick.

Comment: Thanks @guenhter! This did the trick for me as well!